# How can I forward the same port to multiple IPs?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have TL-WR841N router. I'm trying to forward ports but it only accepts a single IP. I need that port forwarded for two PCs, so two IPs.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: You can't so the solution is use a switch so you only forward it a single address

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ... "1. Multiple nodes in your network that want to use the same ports."

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you use capabilities that are provided by installing third party firmware on your router. I wouldn't go this route if you aren't familiar with Linux and working with a terminal interface to some degree. You could get over your head pretty quickly.

You won't be able to do this with your router as-is.

The firmware is called dd-wrt, it is based on Linux, and they have a version for your router. Some straightforward instructions to set that up are here:

http://greggborodaty.com/installing-dd-wrt-tp-link-tl-wr841n/

Alternatively you could use a Linux box with multiple NICs, at least 3, and configure its routing in a nearly identical way.

This will allow you to configure your routing using iptables, a powerful tool but with a steep learning curve. Here is an answered question on how to do what you are looking for with iptables.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896390/cloning-and-forwarding-packets-to-multiple-ip-addresses

Here are is some information on adding iptables rules to a dd-wrt router:
https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Iptables_command

Maybe this should be a comment and not an answer - it's enough info to get you started but there may be some trial and error getting iptables setup correctly.

I've done similar things with iptables and dd-wrt, so it can definitely be done - the sole caveat would be that it is a relatively low end router and its not going to be able to handle high traffic levels - the cpu is the limiting factor.